# IE border-collapse rendering an extra grey line

Tags: css, internet-explorer, border

I am trying to get a table to render on internet explorer, however whenever it does the border renders with an extra grey pixel line attached to it.

Here is some example code, try rendering it on IE9 vs Chrome or Firefox: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/tfzus

(screenshots attached for those who don't want to load it up):

Note the thin grey border on the IE rendering which is not present in chrome's. I have tried solutions from other sources, such as not using the 'border-collapse' styling and instead defining custom borders

```
table tr:first-child td {
  border-top : 1px solid black;
}
```

like so, but to no avail. Does anyone know some css magic that might fix the issue, or is this just an IE bug that won't go away?

Thanks!

CHROME VS IE RENDERING: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPHqg.png

Comment: try css: 
table, td { outline: 0 none; } 
table {border: 0 none; }